# Global JS variable in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: javascript, global-variables, smarty, prestashop-1.6

Where the global JS variable should be declared in Prestashop 1.6, so every .tpl would have access to it?

global.js doesn't make it.

And the code like this, placed in .tpl:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // <![CDATA[
 var test = "test";
 //]]>
 </script>
```

works for the exact .tpl only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (in Hook methods like hookDisplayHeader or in your front controllers):

```
Media::addJsDef([
                'Modal' => true,
                'AjaxNum' => 5
            ]);
```

In other case, you can put your js files in "themes\YOUR-THEME\js\autoload" directory. This only affects the front office

Comment: autoload works in general ... But how to use localization variables in this js file ?

Comment: Plz give an example

Comment: var test = "{l s='Submit'}";

Comment: You can't use this in JS files. You must define these variables in TPL or PHP files. it's better to post new topic for this question.